# Para que serve o illuminate no laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

Atualmente eu tenho me aventurado no `framework laravel` e em alguns casos eu me deparei com um comando no cabeçalho dos meus arquivos logo abaixo do `namespace` chamado `illuminate`.

**Por exemplo:**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

Eu gostaria de saber exatamente como funciona esse `illuminate`? Para que serve? Como eu devo usar ele?

Desde já eu agradeço o apoio.

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta. Se quer mesmo saber, `Illuminate` é o "vendor namespace" do Laravel.

Comment: É um nome dado para um conjunto de libs, assim como CakePHP usa o "namespace vendor" `Cake`, basicamente o Illuminate é o conjunto de libs que compõe o "nucleo" do framework laravel https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/5.6/src/Illuminate ... resumidamente, Illuminate é um nome dado para identificar todas as libs pertencentes a ele. Não se preocupe, não é teoria da conspiração :)

Answer (score 2):

O Illuminate é parte do caminho lógico (namespace).

É como se fosse uma "pasta", contudo, o objetivo é agrupar de maneira lógica as entidades do framework.

Especificamente "Illuminate" senão me engano é a mantenedora do laravel.

Answer (score -2):

Fica dento da pasta "vendor":

C:[caminho do seu projeto]vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\

E dentro dela todas as bibliotecas.